# "Du fasst dir an den Kopf." oder "Du fasst dich an den Kopf."

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, accusative

Heißt es korrekt "Du fasst dir an den Kopf." oder "Du fasst dich an den Kopf."?

Andersherum ist die Frage dazu auch unklar: "Wem fasst du an den Kopf?" oder "Wen fasst du an den Kopf?" – was ist richtig und warum?

Answer (score 3):

In der Onlineversion des Dudens sind unter dem [Stichwort *Kopf*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kopf) zahlreiche *Wendungen, Redensarten, Sprichwörter* aufgeführt. Dort findet man unter anderem auch dem Eintrag

> sich `<Dativ>` an den Kopf fassen/greifen (umgangssprachlich: kein Verständnis für etwas haben: wenn ich so einen Unsinn höre, kann ich mir nur an den Kopf greifen)

Demnach heißt es richtig:

"Du fasst **dir** an den Kopf." bzw. "**Wem** fasst du an den Kopf?"

Answer (score 3):

Beides ist richtig, hat aber eine leicht unterschiedliche Bedeutung. Nehmen wir mal ein etwas "griffigeres" und "berühmteres" Beispiel aus dem klassischen Liedgut:

> Erwin fasst der Heidi von hinten an die Schulter.

Es handelt sich hier um einen *Dativus (in)commodi*, das Dativobjekt ist etwas, zu dessen Vor- oder Nachteil etwas geschieht. Der Satz stellt die Schulter (oder eher, was damit gemeint ist...) als Ziel der Handlung in den Vordergrund.

> Erwin fasst die Heidi von hinten an die Schulter.

Hier haben wir einen Akkusativ, der im Prinzip dasselbe ausdrückt, Heidi ist  direkt das Objekt der Handlung, mit dem etwas gemacht wird und steht damit als Ziel der Handlung im Vordergrund.

Man beachte, dass *die Schulter* hier sowohl im Akkusativ als im Dativ stehen kann, so ist die Schulter im obigen Beispiel das Ziel der Bewegung, während

> Erwin fasst die Heidi von hinten an der Schulter

schon unterstellt, dass er sie schon eine Weile festhält.

Comment: "Er fasst die Heidi an die Schulter" klingt für mich falsch, genauso "Du fasst Dich an den Kopf". Meiner Meinung nach muss da In jedem Fall irgendwo ein Dativ sein - wem fasse ich an den Kopf, bzw. die Schulter? Dass dieser Dativ durch einen Akkusativ ersetzt wird, kenne ich bisher nur von Dialekten.

Answer (score 1):

> Du fasst dir an den Kopf

bedeutet: `Du hältst das für Unsinn`

während

> Du fasst dich an den Kopf

bedeutet: `Du berührst dich (und nicht jemand anderen) mit der Hand am Kopf, weil du dort etwas fühlen willst, z.B. ob deine Haare ordentlich sitzen`